# MongoDB - mongodump collections with a limit

Tags: mongodb, shell, docker, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there a way to mongodump a database with 10+ collections and grab the last 100 objects in each collection?

Here's what I've been training, but it's not working:

```
mongodump --gzip --uri="mongodb://$IP:$PORT/$DB" \
    --collection=$COLLECTION  \
    --archive=$COLLECTION.gz \
    --query="{ \"\$limit\": 100 }"
```

Here's the output:

`Failed: (command failure) Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $limit`

I really need the query limit to work because **some collections have 5gb of data**, and I am just running this for local development purposes so I only need a small sample set of what's actaully in the database/collections

Any help with this would be appreciated!

**Update:**

My objects have a unix `timestamp` field, and I switched the query to this but still no success:

```
// Attempt #2
-q='{"timestamp": { "$gt": "1569888896" }}'

// Attempt #3
-q='{"timestamp":{"$gte": [{ "$toDate": "$timestamp"}, "ISODate(2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z)"]}}'
```

**There's no error in these cases, but it keeps passing back 0 objects!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something working, although not ideal..

If I hard-code in a unix-timestamp **without quotes** it works, and the query itself has to be wrapped in single quotes.

```
--query '{ "timestamp" : { "$gt" : 1569890129 } }'
```

Source:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-query

> You must enclose the query document in single quotes ('{ ... }') to ensure that it does not interact with your shell environment.

Comment: Would still like to be able to just grab the last 100 if possible. Please post your solution if there's a way

Answer (score 2):

You can try mongoexport and mongoimport instead which have sort and limit options, comparatively slower than mongodump, since you need only 100 objects should be fine with your case.

```
mongoexport -h $HOST 
  -u $USERNAME 
  -p $PASSWORD 
  -d $DATABASE 
  -c $COLLECTION 
  -q '{}' 
  --sort '{_id: -1}' 
  --limit 100 
  -o $COLLECTION.csv
```

Comment: I saw this but sadly this won't work since it does not allow to archive, although I might be able to do without the archive so I'll see